# Equivalent to Arrays.asList() but for arrays?

Tags: java

I'd like a convenience method to take a set of parameters and return an array, much like `Arrays.asList(T... items)` will take a set of parameters and return a `List<T>` of those items.

It's easy enough to write one, but does one already exist in java?

**UPDATE**
My bad!  I didn't realize the question was so unclear.  Your questions have forced me to realize that the question isn't quite the question I thought it was.

I have several calls like the following that place various key/values into a Map:

```
        put( Key.get(A.class), new Key[] { Key.get(X.class), Key.get(Y.class), Key.get(Z.class)});
```

... where the map is of type `Map<Key<? extends Foo>,Key<? extends Foo>[]>`

I was looking for a typesafe and succinct way to execute the above statement, and I *thought* that something like the following would work:

```
        put( Key.get(A.class), toArray( Key.get(X.class), Key.get(Y.class), Key.get(Z.class)));
```

... where `toArray()` is defined as something like

```
private static <T> T[] toArray( T... t ) {
    return t;
}
```

However, it turns out that this solution is not typesafe itself, and thus it's really not much more succinct than just creating a new array manually using `new`.  This was the first cause of my misunderstanding.

I thought that I could get typesafety by using a List instead of an array and then using `Arrays.asList()` to populate the values of the list, but it turns out that that's not typesafe either.  This was the second cause of my misunderstanding.  I thought that `Arrays.asList()` would make this statement more succinct than it actually does, and thus I was looking for something that would do the same for me for arrays.

**So I suppose the question is really -** Is there a succinct way to get typesafety in the above situation?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean. How would you call it?

Comment: So you want a method that produces an array out of an arbitrary collection of items?

Comment: "It's easy enough to write one" - maybe showing us what you would write would remove some of our confusion.

Comment: Just noticed your update - see my response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays already have such a shortcut syntax:

```
String[] strArray = {"one", "two", "three"};
```

---

**In response to your update:**

As it seems like you discovered, arrays of parameterized types can never be type-safe. This is one of several limitations due to the fact that [arrays and generics are like oil and water](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm).

A varargs method such as `Arrays.asList` isn't spared from this limitation since varargs works by implicitly creating an array of the comma delimited arguments. In order to have type-safety, you'll need to avoid any solution involving arrays, including varargs.

First, I recommend you change your map's type to hold `List`s instead of arrays:

```
Map<Key<? extends Foo>, List<Key<? extends Foo>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And then build a `List` before putting it in the `Map`:

```
List<Key<? extends Foo>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(Key.get(X.class));
lst.add(Key.get(Y.class));
lst.add(Key.get(Z.class));
map.put(Key.get(A.class), lst);
```

If you want it all in one statement, it's going to be trickier without varargs. Guava's [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) exposes the `of` factory methods taking up to 12 elements before falling back to varargs. If the `List`s in the map aren't going to be modified later, you could store `ImmutableList<Key<? extends Foo>>` and use:

```
map.put(
    Key.get(A.class),
    ImmutableList.of(Key.get(X.class), Key.get(Y.class), Key.get(Z.class))
);
```

In fact you could still take advantage of those factory methods even if the `List` needs to be modifiable by copying the returned `ImmutableList`:

```
map.put(
    Key.get(A.class),
    Lists.newArrayList(ImmutableList.of(
        Key.get(X.class),
        Key.get(Y.class),
        Key.get(Z.class)
    ))
);
```

But then you're introducing overhead just for the sake of style.

---

Side note: if you do happen to be using Guava, you might look at using a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) instead of a `Map` of `List`s.

Answer (score 1):

What would such a method do that the constructor for the array doesn't already?

```
String foo = "FOO";
String bar = "BAR";
String[] strings = new String[]{foo, bar};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public static class ToArray {
    public static <T> T[] toArray(T... items) {
        return items;
    }                
}

public void example() {
    String[] strings = ToArray.toArray("fred", "bob");
}
```

?

Comment: The only downside: it doesn't support primitive arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a `Set` and return a `List` you could use an `ArrayList`:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("str1");
set.add("str2");
set.add("str3");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

If you want an array from a list you could do something like:

```
myList.toArray();
// or even
String[] myStringArray = myList.toArray(new String[]);
```

Comment: I don't think he meant "set" so literally but it's fun to see the different interpretations of such an opaque question :)

Comment: Ha +1 then :) Also note that [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray\(T[]\)) is declared by `Collection` so you can skip the `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? This will return an array because Java [treats the varargs construct as an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). I don't know how to genericize it though.

```
public Object argsToArray(Object... args) {
return args;
}
```